# Set breakpoint for class member function not successful

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a class looks like this:

```
namespace madoka
{
class polarizable_sites
{
public:
void resize(const size_t dim_);
void clear(void);
};
}
```

in gdb, I could set breakpoint on clear by

```
b 'madoka::polarizable_sites::clear()'
```

however, for member function resize, a

```
b 'madoka::polarizable_sites::resize(const size_t)'
```

does not work. GDB reported error:

> the class madoka::polarizable_sites does not have any method named
>   resize(const size_t) Hint: try
>   'madoka::polarizable_sites::resize(const size_t)' or
>   'madoka::polarizable_sites::resize(const size_t)' (Note leading
>   single quote.)

I am wondering why since the function style is auto-completed by TAB.

BTW: I'm using GDB

> GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2 Copyright (C) 2010 Free
>   Software Foundation, Inc.

with compiler'

> g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
>   Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: you can always use file:linenumber.

Comment: @yi_H well, it would be much better to use function name since the linenumber might change if I change the source code and it will be somewhat difficult to trace.

Comment: I'm aware of this, it's just a workaround

Comment: If you have optimizations enabled, it's possible that the compiler automatically inlined the function. Try recompiling with `-O0 -ggdb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the function is inlined. Try adding `__asm int 3` if it's x86 code in GDB syntax and walk the code. This trick has saved me a lot of time when debugging MSVC x86 code.

Comment: this is gcc, don't need to hack ;)

Comment: This might work in GCC `asm("int $0x3");` Remember that this breakpoint will be compiled in and should only be used if you can't break on inline or otherwise optimized code. It will cause changes in code and can show/hide Heisenbugs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the compiler has stripped the const specifier,

Try b 'madoka::polarizable_sites::resize(size_t)'